# Why login is very slow on Ubuntu 13.10 32 bits?

Tags: login

I am Using Ubuntu 13.10 i386 Desktop. After entering password, screen becomes black for more than 10 Seconds [from 10 to 30 Seconds] to load Unity.

I have reset my user account and reboot PC but login delay remains the same.

Which default startup items should be removed?

Comment: What do you call *"Usual Ubuntu 13.10"*? The load speed depends on your PC specs, file system and compatibility. In some cases 10 seconds is not bad at all.

Comment: @Lucio 10Secs is not bad but in my case it speds more then that [it is login delay not boot delay!]

Comment: I am using 13.10 for 3 months it was taking about 2-3 Seconds this is first day that it makes delay to login!!

Comment: Have you installed a new application on that last days?

Comment: @Lucio Yes ____________________________

Comment: I have installed cinnamon

Comment: There you go. That is the reason of why it's taking more than usual. Choice, cinnamon vs performance.

Comment: @Lucio but i have uninstalled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity-greeter
```

if this not solves your problem, try then

```
sudo aptitude reinstall lightdm
```